# How to check GUI on RHEL5 from Windows client

Tags: rhel5, graphical-user-interface

How to check GUI on RHEL5 from Windows client? I got Xterm running using Xming. When I tried
xclock I got
`bash: xclock: command not found`

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can check that your X forwarding is working by running any X command, however if you want to run xclock specifically, then you want the xorg-x11-utils package.

Comment: I am new to linux. Where could I download and how could I install  xorg-x11-utils package for RHEL 5?

Comment: `yum install xorg-x11-utils`

Answer (score 1):

That simply means that xclock is either not in $PATH or not installed at the remote server. Try running another utility that is in $PATH or check your $PATH by:

```
echo $PATH
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing to be aware of is that running an X application remotely does /not/ ensure that the GUI would be working correctly at the physical machine.

The architecture of the X-windows system often seems a little backwards at first, but when you connect to your RHEL box and forward an application, your Windows machine is the X server and your RHEL box is the X client.